# Unable to extract .zip file of Win8 theme

Tags: windows, windows-8, zip, dell-inspiron

I downloaded some themes for Windows 8.

But when I try to open it, I failed to open the .zip file.
Even I was unable to extract the contents.

While tried to extract, it was showing error like :

```
The zip file is empty
```

Why this is happening ?

Actually the theme is from an authorised site and it must have some contents.

I'm on Dell Inspiron, running Win8.

**EDIT:**

I downloaded it on Chrome, it shown as ***Completed***...

Comment: You could try opening the file with a program like peazip but it'd probably be better if you just download it again as it sounds like it didn't download properly

Comment: I downloaded it on Chrome, it shown as *Completed* only..

Comment: Well try opening it peazip but tbh I'd still redownload it as sometimes it can say completed but it really hasn't.  For example I sometimes have iffy Internet and if my connection drops in a download, it usually says "completed" but in reality it just lost connection and "finished". I'm not sure how big the file is but redownloading it is probably the easiest thing to try

Comment: which theme have you downloaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to incompletely downloaded `.zip` files.